# MultiDimensional HashMap with inner maps Stream

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, stream, hashmap

In learning HashMaps,

A hashmap has 4 inner maps of Integer and one for CustomObject.

For a multidimensional hashmap with 6 columns, I am trying to create a Streams method that if I input the key, it would return a value from one of the 4 inner maps.

In draft form, the method is called Profiler_Processor.   Thank you!

[image]

https://github.com/user2021/MultiDimensional_HashMap_Stream/tree/main/src/HashMap2021_JuneStackOverflow

package HashMap2021_JuneStackOverflow;

public class Character {

```
public String temperament;
public String attitude;
public String patience;

public Character(String temperament, String attitude, String patience) {
this.temperament=temperament;
this.attitude=attitude;
this.patience=patience;
}

public String getTemprament() {
    return temperament;
}

public void setTemprament(String temperament) {
    this.temperament = temperament;
}

public String getAttitude() {
    return attitude;
}

public void setAttitude(String attitude) {
    this.attitude = attitude;
}

public String getPatience() {
    return patience;
}

public void setPatience(String patience) {
    this.patience = patience;
}



 }
```

package HashMap2021_JuneStackOverflow;

import java.util.HashMap; import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Character>>>>> PEOPLE = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Character>>>> inner0 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Character>>> inner1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Character>> inner2 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Character> inner3 = new HashMap<>();

    Character ALICE = new Character("Disciplined", "Meticulous", "Perfectionist");
    Character TYRONE = new Character("Strong", "Balanced", "Fair");
    Character MARIA = new Character("Mellow", "Artsy", "Passionate");
    Character JAOKIM = new Character("Intelligent", "Cool", "Delightful");
    Character ZEN = new Character("Smart", "Bubbly", "Chill");

    inner3.put(19000, ALICE);
    inner3.put(19001, TYRONE);
    inner3.put(19002, MARIA);
    inner3.put(19003, JAOKIM);
    inner3.put(19004, ZEN);

    inner2.put(18000, inner3);
    inner2.put(18001, inner3);
    inner2.put(18002, inner3);
    inner2.put(18003, inner3);
    inner2.put(18004, inner3);

    inner1.put(236642118, inner2);
    inner1.put(236642175, inner2);
    inner1.put(236642141, inner2);
    inner1.put(236642130, inner2);
    inner1.put(236642056, inner2);

    inner0.put(5, inner1);
    inner0.put(-1, inner1);
    inner0.put(33, inner1);
    inner0.put(22, inner1);
    inner0.put(8, inner1);

    PEOPLE.put("KEY_A", inner0);
    PEOPLE.put("KEY_B", inner0);
    PEOPLE.put("KEY_C", inner0);
    PEOPLE.put("KEY_D", inner0);
    PEOPLE.put("KEY_E", inner0);

    Profiler_Processor pp = new Profiler_Processor();

    System.out.println(pp.inner0_Processor(PEOPLE, "KEY_A"));

}
```

}

package HashMap2021_JuneStackOverflow;

import java.util.List; import java.util.Map;

public class Profiler_Processor {

```
int inner0_something;

public String inner0_Processor(Map<String, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Character>>>>> incomingToProcess, String input_key) {

    for (Map.Entry<String, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Character>>>>> entry : incomingToProcess.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        
        //NEED HELP HERE
        //List<String> valueList = entry.getValue();

        if (key == null ? input_key == null : key.equals(input_key)) { //                for (String s : valueList) { //                    //for (String value : entry.getValue()) { //   inner0_something = valueList.get(1); //                }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public String inner1_Processor(Map<String, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Character>>>>> incomingToProcess, String input_key) {

    return null;
}

public String inner2_Processor(Map<String, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Character>>>>> incomingToProcess, String input_key) {

    return null;
}

public String inner3_Processor(Map<String, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Character>>>>> incomingToProcess, String input_key) {

    return null;
}

public String character_Processor(Map<String, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Character>>>>> incomingToProcess, String input_key) {

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you really need maps in maps in maps? Also, you should learn about maps and how to access them efficiently.

Comment: Sascha ---  I am willing to pay for any assistance.  I am not a student of programming at college/HS nor a licensed programmer.  Just an amateur, etc. Seriously.   user15793316 -- interesting.  That sounds promising.   Will explore. GOD bless! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you can use an `Optional` to go through your maps. But you need more than one parameter to navigate them. Otherwise you will only get the first level `Map`.

```
return Optional.ofNullable(incomingToProcess.get(input_key))
    .map(map1->map1.get(parameter1))
    .map(map2->map2.get(parameter2))...
    .map(mapN->mapN.get(parameterN)
    .orElse(null);
```